# SQL case statement error handling when there are non-integer values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field of 5 digit codes, and I am trying to create a new flag field if the 5 digit code is between 2 numbers. That part is easy, but there are also a lot of values that have letters and aren't strictly 5 digits. So I'm trying to put a statement at the beginning of the case statement that says if there's an error then set the flag to zero. Or a statement that says if the value is not a number then set to zero.

Here's a sample of listed values:

```
36569
38206
J8502
JAA8C
```

Here is some code I've tried (simplified to get the point across):

```
case 
    when not isnumeric([code]) then 'N'
    when [code] between 50000 and 50005 then 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
end as NewFlag
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about using `try_cast()` or `try_convert()`:

```
(case when try_convert(int, code) between 50000 and 50005
      then 'Y' else 'N'
 end) as newFlag
```

Actually for your particular values, you can do the comparison as strings:

```
(case when code between '50000' and '50005'
      then 'Y' else 'N'
 end) as newFlag
```

This is really a special case, because you have 5 digit codes and you are only concerned about the last character.